# Zend Framework on IIS6 with ISAPI Rewrite

Tags: zend-framework, iis, iis-6, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I'm trying to move a zend application from Apache2 to IIS6, so I decided to install ISAPI Rewrite 3 as recommended [here](http://www.zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html), so I copied the hole app folder to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ and made the IIS Default Web Site to point to the folder /public.

Now, my .htaccess in /public is the following, as suggested [here](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter).

```
RewriteRule (?!\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf))$ index.php
```

But nothing happens, I can reach the homepage OK, and static files too, but no rewriting is done to my URLs, so none of my controllers would work.. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ISAPI_Rewrite 3 then you will need to use Apache version of rules since it is compatible with Apache, i.e.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

or better

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav, but the problem was because I was using the Lite version of Isapi Rewrite, which has to be configured with a single conf file placed in it's installation directory